# Register Explorer COM extension only if specific task was selected

Tags: com, installation, inno-setup

I have a complicated program for working with documents. Client requirement: it should be *conditionally* integrated in Windows Explorer context menu during install, i.e. then user check the corresponding option.

So, in my Inno Setup script `[Tasks]` i've created a separate task named `IntegrateToExporer`.
And in the `[Files]` section - two COM DLL files (x86/x86-64 version) with `regserver` flag.

My question is: how to make `regserver` flag conditional?
it must be applied only if user select `IntegrateToExplorer` task, otherwise file should be copied just like others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two entries in `[Files]`:

- one *with* `regserver` flag to process when `IntegrateToExporer` task is selected
- one *without* the `regserver` flag to process when `IntegrateToExporer` task is *not* selected

```
[Files]
Source: "my.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: regserver; Tasks: IntegrateToExporer
Source: "my.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Tasks: not IntegrateToExporer
```

See [Components and Tasks Parameters](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=componentstasksparams) in Inno Setup documentation.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for this. I'm already read so much Inno documentation and just skip this :(