# Installing Windows shell extension DLL with Inno Setup installer

Tags: windows, shell, com, inno-setup, windows-explorer

I'm developing a shell extension DLL. I want to install it using Inno Setup installer. I seen installers that ask, if I wanted to install shell extension with the program, I would like something similar using Inno Setup installer. How do I go about doing this?

If not, would you be able to direct me to the right path. I been searching for days about any info about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shell extension is just a DLL with a COM class. So just deploy it and register it using the [`regserver` flag](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=regserver):

```
[Files]
Source: "myext.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: regserver
```

---

See also [Register Explorer COM extension only if specific task was selected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29003187/850848).

Comment: Awesome! You just saved me heaps of time. This is what Im looking for direct and precise. I am grateful